# How to get access to a $form in hook_entity_view_display_alter?

Tags: forms, commerce, 9

In Drupal 9, I added a `views_add_to_cart_form` view mode to be able to render a product entity with only the Variations field formatted as add to cart form being displayed. That all works as expected, but I am trying to remove the quantity widget on the commerce add to cart form **for that specific view display** by using `unset($form['quantity']);`.

I am not sure if it is better to bring the view display information into a form_alter, or if it would be cleaner to get the form information in a hook_entity_view_display_alter.

I was trying something like this in the form alter, but felt like it was not at all the right way to go about it

```
$display = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository')->getViewDisplay('commerce_product', 'simple_product', 'views_add_to_cart_form');
if (isset($display)) {
  unset($form['quantity']);
}
```

(I realize my `if (isset($dsiplay)) {` won't cut the mustard...)

It seems like it would be better to use hook_entity_view_display_alter and get the necessary $form stuff in there:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_display_alter().
 */
function MY_entity_view_display_alter(\Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, array $context) {
  if ($context['entity_type'] == 'commerce_product' && $context['view_mode'] == 'views_add_to_cart_form') {
    // Get access to the $form_id and unset($form['quantity']);
  }
}
```

So how do I get access to `&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id` stuff inside hook_entity_view_display_alter?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb if the hook doesn't provide you the object you need, it means you are most likely at the appropriate place to execute your code.

Considering your question, I think you should be using `hook_form_alter` with `$form_id === add_to_cart_form` or something close to that. (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.8.x)

Then you can do the `unset` there.

A better practice would be to give `#access = FALSE` instead of unsetting the element `$form['quantity']['#access] = FALSE;`